# User is Anonymous in DefaultSessionCloseStrategy

Tags: session, sap-commerce-cloud

I have extended the *DefaultSessionCloseStrategy* and created a custom class *DefaultStorefrontSessionCloseStrategy* storefront session timeout functionality. So as per this when user storefront session is expiring, before that user can execute some custom code in this new class. But as soon session timeout is happening, current user is getting *Anonymous* even before the logout. I need the current user details before the session expires.

Any idea what I am missing here ?

And this is working fine in Developer (local) machine. But user is getting anonymous in in cloud (ccv2) environment.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a listener extending `BeforeSessionCloseEvent`.
Then, fetch the user using the Jalosession in the overridden onEvent method,

```
JaloSession session = (JaloSession) beforeSessionCloseEvent.getSource();
UserModel user = this.modelService.get(session.getUser());
```